# How to animate only x Axis in core plot?

Tags: ios, swift, core-plot

I am animating x Axis value in core plot but with that my xAxis , yAxis is also animating and disappearing . My set up for graph is shown in here as I have some issue related to graph data I have asked question and here as u can see in code graph set up is correct : [Graph set up code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38184749/how-to-pass-time-as-xaxis-data-value-in-method-numberforplot-using-core-plot/38187534?noredirect=1#comment63833341_38187534). What is missing? MY code for animation is as below:

```
 let plotSpace = graph.defaultPlotSpace as! CPTXYPlotSpace!
    let location = currentIndex
    let oldRange = CPTPlotRange(location: location , length: kMaxDataPoints - 2)

    let newRange = CPTPlotRange(location: location + 1, length: kMaxDataPoints - 2)

    CPTAnimation.animate(plotSpace, property: "xRange", fromPlotRange: oldRange, toPlotRange: newRange, duration: 1.0)

    currentIndex += 1
```

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "disappear"? This animation doesn't affect any visual properties of the graph.

Comment: Actually Y Axis is also moving to left side of screen, please check I have added image, with animation of xAxis the y Axis is moving

Comment: You can use axis constraints to lock the y-axis in position. Look at the "Real Time Plot" in the *Plot Gallery* example app.

Comment: Thanks , it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(moved from the comments into an answer)*

You can use axis constraints to lock the y-axis in position. Look at the "Real Time Plot" in the Plot Gallery example app.