# Graph plot reference point is changing

Tags: ios, swift, core-plot

I have a weird issue. I have some data on graph and when new data arrives I am inserting that into graph. But issue is new data plotting is starting from first point of already drawn plot not from last point of plot.[image: plot drawing issue] The console prints the correct point but the plotting starts from first point of already drawn plot not from last point of already drawn plot.  My code for graph set up is here :[Code for graph set up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38184749/how-to-pass-time-as-xaxis-data-value-in-method-numberforplot-using-core-plot/38187534?noredirect=1#comment63833341_38187534) and [Code for Axis animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38217491/how-to-animate-only-x-axis-in-core-plot?noredirect=1#comment63872561_38217491)

code :

```
func setGraph() {
    let tts = CPTMutableTextStyle()
    tts.fontSize = 75.0
    tts.color = CPTColor(CGColor: UIColor.blackColor().CGColor)
    tts.fontName = "HelveticaNeue-Bold"
    self.graph.titleTextStyle = tts
    self.graph.title = "Heart Rate vs Time"

    self.graph.applyTheme(CPTTheme(named:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme))
    let plotSpace = graph.defaultPlotSpace as! CPTXYPlotSpace!

    plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = false

    let xRange = plotSpace.xRange.mutableCopy() as! CPTMutablePlotRange
    xRange.locationDouble = Double(0)
    xRange.lengthDouble = Double(kMaxDataPoints)
    plotSpace.xRange = xRange

    let yRange = plotSpace.yRange.mutableCopy() as! CPTMutablePlotRange
    yRange.locationDouble = Double(0)
    yRange.lengthDouble = Double(210)
    plotSpace.yRange = yRange

    graph.addPlotSpace(plotSpace)

    graph.plotAreaFrame!.paddingTop    = 0
    graph.plotAreaFrame!.paddingRight  = 0
    graph.plotAreaFrame!.paddingBottom = graphOffset
    graph.plotAreaFrame!.paddingLeft   = graphOffset
    graph.plotAreaFrame!.masksToBorder = false

    // Grid line styles
    let majorLineStyle          = CPTMutableLineStyle()
    majorLineStyle.lineWidth    = 0.75
    majorLineStyle.lineColor    = CPTColor.redColor()

    let minorLineStyle          = CPTMutableLineStyle()
    minorLineStyle.lineWidth    = 0.25
    minorLineStyle.lineColor    = CPTColor.blackColor()

    //Axis Line colors
    let axisLineStyle           = CPTMutableLineStyle()
    axisLineStyle.lineWidth     = 2.0
    axisLineStyle.lineColor     = CPTColor.blackColor()

    //Axis Label colors
    let labelTextStyle              = CPTMutableTextStyle()
    labelTextStyle.textAlignment    = CPTTextAlignment.Left
    labelTextStyle.color            = CPTColor.blackColor()

    //Axis title color
    let titleTextStyle              = CPTMutableTextStyle()
    titleTextStyle.textAlignment    = CPTTextAlignment.Left
    titleTextStyle.color            = CPTColor.blackColor()
    titleTextStyle.fontSize         = 15

    let dataSourceLinePlot = CPTScatterPlot()
    let lineStyle               = CPTMutableLineStyle()
    lineStyle.lineWidth         = 3.0
    lineStyle.lineColor         = CPTColor.blueColor()
    dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle
    dataSourceLinePlot.identifier    = kPlotIdentifier
    //        dataSourceLinePlot.dataSource    = self

    let xts = CPTMutableTextStyle()
    xts.color = CPTColor(componentRed: 255.0, green: 255.0, blue: 255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
    let timeformatter = CPTTimeFormatter(dateFormatter: dateFormatter)
    timeformatter.referenceDate = NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(startTimeInterval)

    currentdate = timeformatter.referenceDate

    let axisSet = graph.axisSet as! CPTXYAxisSet!

    let xAxis = axisSet.xAxis as CPTXYAxis!
    xAxis.axisTitle = CPTAxisTitle(text: "Elapsed Time", textStyle: xts)
    xAxis.labelFormatter = timeformatter
    xAxis.majorGridLineStyle = majorLineStyle
    xAxis.minorGridLineStyle = minorLineStyle
    xAxis.majorIntervalLength = NSNumber(double: 30.0)

    let yAxis = axisSet.yAxis as CPTXYAxis!
    yAxis.axisTitle = CPTAxisTitle(text: "Heart Rate", textStyle: xts)
    let axisFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    axisFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
    axisFormatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1
    yAxis.labelFormatter = axisFormatter
    yAxis.titleOffset = 35.0
    yAxis.majorIntervalLength = 20
    yAxis.majorGridLineStyle = majorLineStyle
    yAxis.minorGridLineStyle = minorLineStyle
    yAxis.axisConstraints = CPTConstraints(lowerOffset: 0.0)

    graph.addPlot(dataSourceLinePlot)
    self.IBviewGraph.hostedGraph = self.graph
     setGraphData()
}

func setGraphData()
{
 self.plot.dataSource = self
        let actualPlotStyle = self.plot.dataLineStyle!.mutableCopy() as! CPTMutableLineStyle
        actualPlotStyle.lineWidth = 2.0
        actualPlotStyle.lineColor = CPTColor(CGColor: (UIColor.blueColor().CGColor))
        self.plot.dataLineStyle = actualPlotStyle
        self.plot.interpolation = .Curved
        self.graph.addPlot(self.plot)
}
```

Now when i receive new data :

```
graphData.removeAtIndex(0)
 plot.deleteDataInIndexRange(NSMakeRange(0, 1))
let location = currentIndex
let oldRange = CPTPlotRange(location: location , length: kMaxDataPoints)
let newRange = CPTPlotRange(location: location + 30, length: kMaxDataPoints)
CPTAnimation.animate(plotSpace, property: "xRange", fromPlotRange: oldRange, toPlotRange: newRange, duration: CGFloat(1.0 / kFrameRate))
graphData.append((newTime,data.1))
plot.insertDataAtIndex(UInt(graphData.count - 1), numberOfRecords: 1)
```

Comment: It would help to not link to code and compile your code from your provided code in the linked question and the answer to your question. Instead place your code directly in this question.

Comment: You are appending to your graphdata an item at position `(newTime, data.1)`.  Is `newTime` what you expect it to be?  You don't have it's value shown in the code anywhere.

Comment: How are you computing the data values in the plot datasource? You can't use `NSDate()` in the calculations like you did in the axis setup because that represents the current date and time and will change while the app is running.

Comment: The data source values are coming from web service