# How to get xAxis label text value from core plot axisLabels array?

Tags: ios, swift, core-plot

Actually I want to get string value of my xAxis label . How to get that? I have an array of labels of xAxis :

```
    let xAxis = axisSet.xAxis as CPTXYAxis!
    let label = xAxis.axisLabels?
```

So this is returning me all the label values which is visible on screen. As [reference to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38184749/2849443) I need to calculate points for mapping my value to plot that on xAxis. But after I scroll my graph how to get fist label value again? I want string value which is I am displaying on map that is lets say for example : "17:04:05". How to get that value from array ? As this `axisLabels` array returns value which is not in shorted order and i want first label value which is visible on my graph.  Out put of array is shown below:

```
Optional("[<<CPTAxisLabel: 0x7fe5e858b910> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x7fe5e84501d0> bounds: {{0, 0}, {58, 21}}> \"11:47:46\">}>, <<CPTAxisLabel: 0x7fe5e858b5f0> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x7fe5e858b7f0> bounds: {{0, 0}, {58, 21}}> \"11:41:16\">}>, <<CPTAxisLabel: 0x7fe5e85a1070> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x7fe5e8586cd0> bounds: {{0, 0}, {58, 21}}> \"11:46:16\">}>, <<CPTAxisLabel: 0x7fe5e86adf70> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x7fe5e86b6b90> bounds: {{0, 0}, {58, 21}}> \"11:44:46\">}>, <<CPTAxisLabel: 0x7fe5e8591660> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x7fe5e85918a0> bounds: {{0, 0}, {58, 21}}> \"11:43:16\">}>, <<CPTAxisLabel: 0x7fe5e853fde0> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x7fe5e8511530> bounds: {{0, 0}, {58, 21}}> \"11:48:16\">}>, <<CPTAxisLabel: 0x7fe5e858bab0> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x7fe5e85915a0> bounds: {{0, 0}, {58, 21}}> \"11:41:46\">}>, <<CPTAxisLabel: 0x7fe5e87b2e00> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x7fe5e876f990> bounds: {{0, 0}, {58, 21}}> \"11:46:46\">}>, <<CPTAxisLabel: 0x7fe5e857dff0> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x7fe5e8587690> bounds: {{0, 0}, {58, 21}}> \"11:45:16\">}>, <<CPTAxisLabel: 0x7fe5e8588f80> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x7fe5e858acf0> bounds: {{0, 0}, {58, 21}}> \"11:43:46\">}>, <<CPTAxisLabel: 0x7fe5e86830c0> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x7fe5e8684e30> bounds: {{0, 0}, {58, 21}}> \"11:48:46\">}>, <<CPTAxisLabel: 0x7fe5e8588ce0> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x7fe5e8588ec0> bounds: {{0, 0}, {58, 21}}> \"11:42:16\">}>, <<CPTAxisLabel: 0x7fe5e85a1290> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x7fe5e8584c80> bounds: {{0, 0}, {58, 21}}> \"11:47:16\">}>, <<CPTAxisLabel: 0x7fe5e845df20> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x7fe5e845e040> bounds: {{0, 0}, {58, 21}}> \"11:45:46\">}>, <<CPTAxisLabel: 0x7fe5e8590a60> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x7fe5e8590ca0> bounds: {{0, 0}, {58, 21}}> \"11:44:16\">}>, <<CPTAxisLabel: 0x7fe5e8766660> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x7fe5e8748c90> bounds: {{0, 0}, {58, 21}}> \"11:49:16\">}>, <<CPTAxisLabel: 0x7fe5e858b8b0> {<<<CPTTextLayer: 0x7fe5e85909a0> bounds: {{0, 0}, {58, 21}}> \"11:42:46\">}>]")
```

As you can see its not in sorted order or is not in order which is displaying on graph and I want only first string which is showing on graph. help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you want the first label or the value of the left side of the plot area, whether it has a label or not?

Comment: I want string value which is printing on left side of the xAxis, which is first lable ex: "17:05:25"

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the set of axis labels. For each one, the `contentLayer` is an instance of `CPTTextLayer`. Read the `text` property and convert the time string to the data value using the label formatter. Find the smallest value in the set of data values.